# Leitura de arquivos em PROLOG

Tags: prolog

Como posso ler em PROLOG um arquivo.txt dessa forma:

```
iago.neves pedro.santos
joao.vitor larissa.figueiredo
```

Sendo Iago Neves, um nome e Pedro Santos outro nome, João Vitor e Larissa Figueiredo. Tentei usar o comando read, mas ele para a leitura até o ponto e não consigo ler os sobrenomes junto com os nomes de maneira correta .
Alguém, por favor?

Answer (score 1):

O comando [`read/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=read/1) serve para ler **termos** de um arquivo com a mesma sintaxe do Prolog. Para ler conteúdo arbitrário (i.e. strings) você vai precisar dos métodos de [leitura de caracteres primitivos](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=chario), como por exemplo o [`get_char/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=get_char/1). Um exemplo (sem entrar no mérito da codificação do arquivo, que eu assumo que você já especificou ao abrir a *stream* de entrada) seria:

```
ler_chars(S) :-
    get_char(C),
    ler_resto(C,S).

ler_resto(end_of_file, []).
ler_resto(C, [C|R]) :-
    get_char(C2),
    ler_resto(C2, R).
```

Após chamar `ler_chars` numa *stream*, seu conteúdo será retornado em uma lista de caracteres. Se você quiser esse conteúdo em uma string, basta chamar [`atom_chars/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=atom_chars/2) no resultado:

```
?- abrir_stream, ler_chars(Chars), atom_chars(String, Chars).
```

Mas uma opção melhor é interpretar o conteúdo desse arquivo através de uma gramática DCG. Pelo que eu entendi, você tem uma série de nomes separados por espaços ou quebras de linha, certo? E cada nome consiste em `nome.sobrenome`. Isso expresso em DCG ficaria:

```
nomes([]) --> [].
nomes([Nome|R]) --> nome(Nome), [' '], nomes(R).
nomes([Nome|R]) --> nome(Nome), ['\n'], nomes(R).
nomes([Nome]) --> nome(Nome).

nome(pessoa(Nome,Sobrenome)) --> palavra(CNome), ['.'], palavra(CSobrenome),
                                 { atom_chars(Nome, CNome),
                                   atom_chars(Sobrenome, CSobrenome) }.

palavra([]) --> [].
palavra([C|R]) --> [C], { is_alpha(C) }, palavra(R).
```

Chamando esse código no resultado da leitura te produz uma lista onde cada elemento é da forma `pessoa(Nome,Sobrenome)`:

```
?- abrir_stream, ler_chars(Chars), nomes(Pessoas, Chars, []).

Pessoas = [pessoa(iago, neves), pessoa(pedro, santos), pessoa(joao, vitor), pessoa(larissa, figueiredo)]
```

[Exemplo no ideone.](https://ideone.com/RzBFue)