# Como verificar quais itens da lista cumprem determinada condição?

Tags: prolog

Como fazer uma função chamada `LinhasLongas`, que recebe 2 parâmetros no mínimo, para decidir se uma linha de ônibus é longa ou não?

Os dados estão em uma lista de pares pontuados, tal como:

```
((1 . 2)(2 . 3)(5 . 3)(2 . 7)(10 . 20))
```

Número da linha no exemplo é o 1 do primeiro par pontuado, e quantos pontos tem a linha é o 2 do primeiro par pontuado.

Precisa resultar uma lista dos pontos que têm uma quantidade de pontos maiores que o parâmetro passado. Supor existente uma função chamada `maior`, que recebe `a` e `b` e retorna se `a>b`.

Comment: Mas é Lisp ou Prolog? Ou você quer fazer em ambas as linguagens? (e nesse caso, seria melhor fazer duas perguntas, não?) A propósito, seu problema maior é na leitura dos dados nesse formato específico, na lógica da função em si, ou ambos? Já tem alguma coisa pronta? Essa pergunta me parece um tanto ampla, mas posso tentar responder algo (em Prolog, não sei em Lisp).

Comment: prolog, em ambos,n tenho nd pronto!

Comment: Esse formato de entrada é bastante estranho... Isso é algum exercício ou coisa desse tipo, ou é um problema prático? [Nessa pergunta relacionada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/66028/215) eu explico como ler dados de formato arbitrário de um arquivo de entrada ou do stdin (usando DCG), teria apenas que adaptar. Quanto à função em si, vou dar uma resposta.

Comment: um exercicio de faculdade,nada complicado ou que necessita de muitas validações. Apenas para se ter uma ideia geral de prolog. Estou com dificuldades de intendimento .

Comment: Ok. Leitura e escrita em Prolog é bastante chata mesmo... Mas estou deixando isso de fora da resposta, pois senão fica muito amplo. Quanto à lógica da função, a resposta que estou escrevendo usa `member/2`, caso você não conheça esse *built-in* eu sugiro (pra reforçar seu aprendizado) tentar implementar esse predicado você mesmo. `member(?X,?L)` tem sucesso se o primeiro argumento `X` é um elemento qualquer do segundo argumento `L` (uma lista).

Answer (score 1):

Prolog usa uma estratégia de execução chamada **busca em profundidade com retrocesso**. Isso significa que dadas duas chamadas, ele tentará achar uma solução pra primeira, em seguida uma pra segunda, e se por alguma razão a segunda falhar ele "desfaz" o que ele já fez até o momento e tenta achar alguma *outra* solução pra primeira chamada, tentando de novo a segunda, etc, até que ele encontre alguma solução ou conclua que não há nenhuma.

Dessa forma, dado o *built-in* [`member/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=member/2) (que tem sucesso se o elemento `X` está na lista `L`) e a função `maior/2` que - como estabelecido na pergunta - recebe `A` e `B` e tem sucesso se `A > B` (nota: "tem sucesso", e não "retorna"; Prolog não tem funções, tem **relações**, de modo que estritamente falando uma relação Prolog não "retorna" nada) temos:

```
?- L = [[1,2], [2,3], [5,3], [2,7], [10,20]], member([Linha,Pontos], L), maior(Pontos, 3).
```

O que o motor Prolog fará é o seguinte:

- O primeiro membro de `L` é `[1,2]`, então `[Linha,Pontos] = [1,2]`; ou seja, `Linha = 1` e `Pontos = 2`;
- `maior(2, 3)` falhará; o retrocesso "desunificará" `Linha` e `Ponto`, voltando elas a serem variáveis livres;
- O próximo membro de `L` é `[2,3]`, então `[Linha,Pontos] = [2,3]`; como antes, `maior(3,3)` falhará e o retrocesso ocorrerá de novo;
- O próximo membro de `L` é `[5,3]`, então `[Linha,Pontos] = [5,3]`; como antes, `maior(3,3)` falhará e o retrocesso ocorrerá de novo;
- O próximo membro de `L` é `[2,7]`, então `[Linha,Pontos] = [2,7]`;
- `maior(7,3)` terá sucesso. Como é a última chamada, a expressão inteira terá concluído com sucesso, e o que será retornado é:

  ```
  Linha = 2
  Pontos = 7
  ```

Se você pedir "mais resultados" (`;` na linha de comando) então ele fará novamente o retrocesso, tentando o par `[10,20]` (que terá sucesso) e retornando isso. Se você pedir "mais resultados" de novo, como não há mais nenhum elemento na lista ele retornará `no` (ou `false`, dependendo da implementação).

OK, mas e se você quiser não um resultado mas **todos** os resultados? Aí é que entra o *built-in* [`findall/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall/3): ele estabelece uma variável "alvo", um predicado a ser testado, e unifica o terceiro argumento com a lista de valores para essa variável que satisfazem ao predicado dado. Exemplo:

```
?- findall(Linha, (
       L = [[1,2], [2,3], [5,3], [2,7], [10,20]], member([Linha,Pontos], L), maior(Pontos, 3)
   ), Lista).

Lista = [2,10]

?- findall(Linha, (
       L = [[1,2], [2,3], [5,3], [2,7], [10,20]], member([Linha,Pontos], L), maior(Pontos, 2)
   ), Lista).

Lista = [2,5,2,10]
```

Em outras palavras, o que o `findall` faz é mais ou menos o mesmo que você fazendo uma consulta e pedindo "mais resultados" até não ter mais nenhum, e montar uma lista com uma expressão qualquer envolvendo cada resultado.

Concluindo, assumindo que você possua um meio de ler a sua entrada e transformar numa lista de pares ([nessa pergunta relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/66028/215) eu dou uma resposta mostrando um modo de fazer isso, via DCG), o que resta então é encapsular a lógica acima em uma relação separada:

```
lista_maiores(L, Valor, Maiores) :-
    findall(Linha, (member([Linha,Pontos], L), maior(Pontos, Valor)), Maiores).

?- lista_maiores([[1,2], [2,3], [5,3], [2,7], [10,20]], 2, Lista).

    Lista = [2,5,2,10]
```

[Exemplo no ideone](http://ideone.com/2cJleb).

Comment: P.S. Agora que percebi que você queria que a função se chamasse `LinhasLongas`. Em Prolog, tudo que começa com uma letra maiúscula ou um *underscore* (`_`) é uma variável, de modo que não é possível se ter uma função com esse nome (a menos que se faça alguma "gambiarra" usando reflexão - tipo usando `=..` e `assert` - e *outra* gambiarra semelhante na hora de chamar a função...).

Comment: nossa muito ,obrigado! deu-se para se ter uma ideia de como se fazer!!